# Will a memory access to a dynamically allocated variable with attribute "volatile" cause cache misses for every access?

Tags: c, caching, volatile

My understanding is that the "volatile" qualifier says compiler not to cache the variable and read it from main memory for each access. And I believe that processor can't get hold of memory without bringing it to cache, Please clarify Thanks

Comment: `volatile` primarily affects optimization, not caching (though it may affect caching as a side effect)

Comment: "caching" variable in the context of optimizing compilers means  i.e. keeping it in registers without reloading from the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard leaves it to each C implementation to define what constitutes access to a volatile object. C 2018 6.7.3 8 says:

> … What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.

In typical C implementations, accessing a volatile object requires a load or store instruction, so the processor does access memory whenever the C program accesses the object. Further, cache coherency is often provided by hardware, so that other threads or processes accessing the same memory see changes in a timely manner (that is, in some sequence consistent with program semantics), but details vary.

Since access is implementation-defined, a C implementation could define access to a volatile object to require some additional memory synchronization or could define it in such a way as to be useless, merely accessing whatever register the compiler has cached the value in.